# How to find total counts of a specific word in RDD from text file in pyspark using rdd.sum()

Tags: pyspark, substring, rdd

I have a text file

```
123 Twinkle twinkle littlestar and moon
124 Twinkletwinkle little star and star
125 Twinkle twinkle littlestar and star
126 Twinkletwinkle little star and moon
127 Twinkle twinkle littlestar and moon
128 Twinkletwinkle little star and star
129 Twinkle twinkle littlestar
130 Twinkletwinkle little star
```

Suppose I want to find how many times "star" has appeared as a word in the file not as substring like littlestar. And also some lines have multiple appearances. I want to find the counts of appearance as word in each line and then sum it using rdd.sum()

```
rdd.filter(lambda x: "star" in x).count()
```

the above code gives the number of lines which has star as either word or substring both which is 8

I want the output in such a way that it will execute the following at the end

```
count_list=[0,2,1,1,0,2,0,1] #"star"counts in each line as word
rdd=sc.parallelize(count_list)
rdd.sum()
>> 7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way you can do:

```
textFile = spark.read.text('sample.txt')

textFile.rdd.map(lambda x: x[0].split(' ').count('star')).sum()

7
```

Comment: i was wondering why it does not work when i read the textfile as following

`from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
test=sc.textFile('test.txt')`

and do
 `test.map(lambda x: x[0].split(' ').count('star')).sum()`
its showing error.

Comment: glad it helps, which version are you using?

Comment: i am using 2.4.4

Comment: not sure, don't know the reason exactly. I always use spark session to read txt, csv files mostly.